# Deploying Rails Apps to heroku from multiple PC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

I am Rails newbie and learning to build rails apps. First time I deploy from my home PC and then everything just fine, then I want to work on the apps and deploy from my laptop and work PC, but it turn out I cannot deploy my update code. Every time I push to github work fine, but when I want to push to heroku it didn't deploy my code. I opened my heroku apps, and it's obviously out-dated

```
$ git push

Counting objects: 26, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.22 KiB, done.
Total 14 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:myprofile/myapp.git
bb15762..94d0674  master -> master

$ git push heroku master

Everything up-to-date
```

I use Linux on virtualBox and I clone it for each PC, so all has identical ID and MAC I believe. I did all necessary `git remote add heroku` and in the end heroku just ignore my update code and never rerun the build.

I tried to run this command `$ heroku rollback`    `$ heroku restart --app MyApp` as well in order to get my update code push to heroku still did't work either. When I run `$ heroku info --app MyApp` it give all my app info

```
=== my-app
Addons:        heroku-postgresql:dev
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:my-app.git
Owner Email:   myemail@gmail.com
Repo Size:     13M
Slug Size:     17M
Stack:         cedar
Web URL:       http://my-app.herokuapp.com/
```

I just wonder what happen and only using my Home PC to push to heroku is kind of annoying for me because I need to work on it anywhare if that possible. Thank you for the all future answers!

When I call this command `git remote -v` it gives me these:

```
all git@github.com:myprofile/my-aap.git (fetch)
all git@github.com:myprofile/my-aap.git (push)
github  git@github.com:myprofile/my-aap.git (fetch)
github  git@github.com:myprofile/my-aap.git (push)
heroku  git@github.com:myprofile/my-aap.git (fetch)
heroku  git@github.com:myprofile/my-aap.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:myprofile/my-aap.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:myprofile/my-aap.git (push)
```

Comment: what does ```git remote -v``` say on the machines that can't update heroku?

Comment: 'git remote -v` gives me those line of logs

Comment: so... and you are not suspicious about all those origins, that point to github instead of heroku?

Comment: Yeah, I remove it and re point to heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. @phoet - Thank you for the hints. I was adding wrong remote master to heroku that is the reason why my push didn't go through.

So I remove all the existing remote and adding again. Now everything works with little adjustment.